# The fundamental group of an algebraic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Question: Let $X$ be a non-singular algebraic surface of general type. Suppose that the canonical class $K_X$ is an integer multiple of another class $L$. Let $\Sigma_k$ be a smooth curve of genus $k$ that represents the class $L$ in $X$ (here I assume such $\Sigma_k$ exists). Is it true that $\pi_1(\Sigma_k)$ surjects into $\pi_1(X)$? Do you know any relationships between them?

Thanks

Comment: By a result of Nori (Corr 2.4B in "Zariski's conjecture and related problems"), if $C^2>0$ for an irreducible curve $C$ on a surface $X$ then $\pi_1(C)$ surjects on $\pi_1(X)$. Since $K^2>0$ for a general type surface it follows that $\Sigma_k^2>0$ as well, in your question, hence the required surjection. 

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $L$ is an ample line bundle and hence $\Sigma_k$ is a smooth ample divisor. The Lefschetz hyperplane theorem now implies that $\pi_1(\Sigma_k)\to\pi_1(X)$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you. Can I apply Lefschetz hyperplane theorem if it is not known $L$ can be represented by a complex submanifold? All I know is my $\Sigma_k$ is a symplectic submanifold of $X$.

Comment: Good point. Above I assumed that $\Sigma$ is the zero-set of a global section of $L$.

Comment: Maybe this is trivial, but I don't see why $L$ is ample and not only big.